# Math content in forest

Tags: math-mode, forest

I'm trying to modify an example given in the [`forest` manual](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest.pdf). However, the template is setup in such a way that I'm not able to enter more "advanced" math contents, such as `\nicefrac` or `\underset`. In the following MWE, for instance, I'd like to replace `a/b` with `\nicefrac{a}{b}` and `c/d` with `\underset{d}{c}`. But I got errors when trying to do so. Any ideas why?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,nicefrac}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\def\getfirst#1;#2\endget{#1} 
\def\getsecond#1;#2\endget{#2}
\forestset{declare toks={elo}{}} % edge label options
\begin{forest}
  anchors/.style={anchor=#1,child anchor=#1,parent anchor=#1},
  for tree={
    font=\footnotesize,
    s sep=0.5em,l+=8mm,
    if n children=0{anchors=north}{
      if n=1{anchors=south east}{anchors=south west}},
    content format={$\forestoption{content}$}
  },
  anchors=south, outer sep=2pt,
  dot/.style={tikz+={\fill (.child anchor) circle[radius=2pt];}},
  for descendants=dot,
  decision edge label/.style n args=3{
    edge label/.expanded={node[midway,auto=#1,anchor=#2,\forestoption{elo}]{\strut$#3$}}
  },
  decision/.style={if n=1
    {decision edge label={left}{east}{#1}}
    {decision edge label={right}{west}{#1}}
  },
  delay={for descendants={
    decision/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getsecond#1\endget}{content},
    content/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getfirst#1\endget}{content},
  }},
[N
  [;{a/b}[{2,3};m][{2,3};n]] % \nicefrac{a}{b} doesn't work
  [;{c/d}[{2,3};m][{2,3};n]] % \underset{d}{c} doesn't work
]
\end{forest}    
\end{document}
```

## Current Output

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `forest` package uses `\edef` where it should use `\protected@edef`.

So the fact that `\nicefrac` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` doesn't help. The `\underset` command is fragile to begin with, so it will fail anyway, but the standard method of prefixing it with `\protect` doesn't work because of the issue mentioned at the beginning.

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,nicefrac,etoolbox}
\usepackage{forest}

\robustify{\nicefrac}
\robustify{\underset}
```

Now `\nicefrac` (the name is badly chosen, it should be `\uglyfrac`) and `\underset` can be used.

An alternative method is to do

\newcommand{\extraprotect}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmMzL.png){%
     \unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}%
   }

In the case of

```
\newcommand{\payoff}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
```

you can use

```
\extraprotect{\payoff{a & b \\ c & d}}
```

in the argument to `forest`, say

```
[;{\extraprotect{\payoff{a & b \\ c & d}}}[{2,3};m][{2,3};n]]
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,nicefrac,etoolbox}
\usepackage{forest}

\robustify{\nicefrac}
\robustify{\underset}

\newcommand{\extraprotect}[1]{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}
\newcommand{\payoff}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\def\getfirst#1;#2\endget{#1} 
\def\getsecond#1;#2\endget{#2}
\forestset{declare toks={elo}{}} % edge label options
\begin{forest}
  anchors/.style={anchor=#1,child anchor=#1,parent anchor=#1},
  for tree={
    font=\footnotesize,
    s sep=0.5em,l+=8mm,
    if n children=0{anchors=north}{
      if n=1{anchors=south east}{anchors=south west}},
    content format={$\forestoption{content}$}
  },
  anchors=south, outer sep=2pt,
  dot/.style={tikz+={\fill (.child anchor) circle[radius=2pt];}},
  for descendants=dot,
  decision edge label/.style n args=3{
    edge label/.expanded={node[midway,auto=#1,anchor=#2,\forestoption{elo}]{\strut$#3$}}
  },
  decision/.style={if n=1
    {decision edge label={left}{east}{#1}}
    {decision edge label={right}{west}{#1}}
  },
  delay={for descendants={
    decision/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getsecond#1\endget}{content},
    content/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getfirst#1\endget}{content},
  }},
[N
  [;{\nicefrac{a}{b}}[{2,3};m][{2,3};n]] % \nicefrac{a}{b} doesn't work
  [;{\extraprotect{\payoff{c\\d}}}[{2,3};m][{2,3};n]] % \underset{d}{c} doesn't work
]
\end{forest}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I `\robustify` a command that involves an environment? For example, I have `\newcommand\payoff[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}`, using `\robustify{\payoff}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @HerrK. `\newrobustcmd\payoff[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}`, but you'll have problems with ``\\`` in the argument (and ``\robustify\\`` won't work).

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I found that entering using the `label` option would bypass the problem: `payoff/.style={label={below:$\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}$}}`, and use `payoff={1\\0}` works fine.

Comment: @HerrK. I added another workaround, but your `.style` seems good.

Comment: @egreg, could you point me to the improper use(s) of `\edef` in the package code?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović There are several of them and I'm not going deep into the code. Some of the `\edef` might be safe, the ones that should become `\protected@edef` are those that receive text for typesetting (like in the question).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with the `forest` package itself, but rather lies the decision tree style (which can be, admittedly, found in the manual), which gets two oppurtunities to expand `\nicefrac` or `\underset`.

1. `edge label` is used with the `.expanded` handler, in order to expand `\forestoption{elo}`. Solution: protect the content of the edge node, `#3`, by `\unexpanded`.
2. `decision` and `content` are fed by the `.expanded` handler, in order to expand `\getfirst` and `getsecond`. Solution: `.expand once` suffices.

Code:

```
% bad line
edge label/.expanded={node[midway,auto=#1,anchor=#2,\forestoption{elo}]{\strut$#3$}}
% good line
edge label/.expanded={node[midway,auto=#1,anchor=#2,\forestoption{elo}]{\strut$\unexpanded{#3}$}}

% bad line
decision/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getsecond#1\endget}{content},
% good line
decision/.expand once/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getsecond#1\endget}{content},

% bad line
content/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getfirst#1\endget}{content},
% good line
content/.expand once/.wrap pgfmath arg={\getfirst#1\endget}{content},
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and again for the great package!